# Make a container fluid properly enclose text

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am making a page that uses Twitter Bootstrap. I just want a line to be written in a container that is responsive.

What I have tried is:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span10" style="background-color:red;
    border-radius:30px;color:powderBlue">
      <p style="font-size: 22px">My sample text here.</p>
    </div>

 </div> 
  </div>
```

But this is not working correctly because some of my text is going out of bounds of the red background.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/iAXBderO94

Answer (score 0):

Just put padding on the span10 class

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
 <div class="row-fluid">
   <div class="span10" style="background-color:red;
    border-radius:30px;color:powderBlue; padding: 8px 30px;">
      <p style="font-size: 22px">My sample text here.</p>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Leaving some padding from the left might work.

Try this

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid" >
<div class="span10" style="background-color:red;padding-left:10px;border-radius:30px;color:powderBlue">
    <p style="font-size: 22px">My sample text here.</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```